# Trouble installing RVM, wrong user directory?

Tags: installation, rvm

I am trying to install rvm, running `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s --rails --autolibs=enabled`. On my current OSX (10.8.4) install, my user directory is `/users/regis`, but installing rvm  fails, with the following message: `mkdir: /Users/regiszaleman/.rvm/src: Permission denied`... 'regiszaleman' used to be my user directory in a previous computer, from which I have transferred a long time ago... Any ideas?

Comment: check `env | grep regiszaleman`

Comment: Thanks mpapis - did not return anything though...

Comment: how about `/etc/rvmrc` and `~/.rvmrc`? ... if those two ar empty you can also trace the process with: `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -x -- --trace` - the output will be huge but will contain the answer to why ...

Comment: Thank you mpapis! I found I had some wrong info I must have carried with me from my old computer in `~/.rvmrc` which referred to the old user dir name. I cleaned it up and ran the install without trouble!